Amazon Redshift unnest(array[]) not available
We were previously using an azure database and moving to Amazon redshift so I am in the process of moving report queries. I have a fair few with the unnest(array[]) function however I'm not sure what to use instead?
Here is a simplified version of the query I am trying to modify - basically there is one column with the name of the field, and another with the actual date from the columns themselves. In an attempt to make the moving process as simple as possible, I would like to keep the field name column if possible.
select
    rp.id,
    unnest(array['colo_l2_submitted_telstra_nbn_vha_f__c',
    'colo_l2_submitted_telstra_nbn_vha_a__c',
    'colo_l2_approved_telstra_nbn_vha_f__c',
    'colo_l2_approved_telstra_nbn_vha_a__c',
    'colo_l3_submitted_telstra_nbn_vha_f__c',
    'colo_l3_submitted_telstra_nbn_vha_a__c',
    'colo_l3_approved_telstra_nbn_vha_f__c',
    'colo_l3_approved_telstra_nbn_vha_a__c',
    'colo_l6_submitted_telstra_nbn_vha_f__c',
    'colo_l6_submitted_telstra_nbn_vha_a__c',
    'colo_l6_approved_telstra_nbn_vha_f__c',
    'colo_l6_approved_telstra_nbn_vha_a__c',
    'in_service_rfs_complete_f__c',
    'in_service_rfs_complete_a__c',
    'as_built_completed__c']) as field_name,
    unnest(array[rot.colo_l2_submitted_telstra_nbn_vha_f__c,
    rot.colo_l2_submitted_telstra_nbn_vha_a__c,
    rot.colo_l2_approved_telstra_nbn_vha_f__c,
    rot.colo_l2_approved_telstra_nbn_vha_a__c,
    rot.colo_l3_submitted_telstra_nbn_vha_f__c,
    rot.colo_l3_submitted_telstra_nbn_vha_a__c,
    rot.colo_l3_approved_telstra_nbn_vha_f__c,
    rot.colo_l3_approved_telstra_nbn_vha_a__c,
    rot.colo_l6_submitted_telstra_nbn_vha_f__c,
    rot.colo_l6_submitted_telstra_nbn_vha_a__c,
    rot.colo_l6_approved_telstra_nbn_vha_f__c,
    rot.colo_l6_approved_telstra_nbn_vha_a__c,
    rot.in_service_rfs_complete_f__c,
    rot.in_service_rfs_complete_a__c,
    rot.as_built_completed__c]) as field_date
from
    s.project rp
left join s.otherproject rot on rp.id = rot.project__c

I have tried a couple of union functions but did not come out as expected.
Sample Data
Original Data
id          colo_l2_submitted_telstra_nbn_vha_f__c     colo_l2_submitted_telstra_nbn_vha_a__c
P-01111     1/01/2020                                  2/01/2023
P-12224     1/02/2022                                  3/01/2023
P-23654     2/02/2022                                  4/01/2023
unnested query
  select
    rp.name as project id,
    unnest(array['colo_l2_submitted_telstra_nbn_vha_f__c',  'colo_l2_submitted_telstra_nbn_vha_a__c']) as field_name,
    unnest(array[rot.colo_l2_submitted_telstra_nbn_vha_f__c, rot.colo_l2_submitted_telstra_nbn_vha_a__c]) as field_date
from
    project rp
left join otherproject rot on
    rp.id = rot.project__c

Outcome of unnested query:
Project_id Field Name Field Date
P-01111         colo_l2_submitted_telstra_nbn_vha_f__c       1/01/2020
P-01111         colo_l2_submitted_telstra_nbn_vha_a__c       2/01/2023
P-12224         colo_l2_submitted_telstra_nbn_vha_f__c       1/02/2023
P-12224         colo_l2_submitted_telstra_nbn_vha_a__c       3/01/2023
P-23654         colo_l2_submitted_telstra_nbn_vha_f__c       2/02/2023
P-23654         colo_l2_submitted_telstra_nbn_vha_a__c       4/01/2023

In Redshift the equivalent to the “array()” function would be json_parse().  This function takes a valid JSON string and converts it into a SUPER data type column.
Once you have these arrays as SUPER type, you can unnest them. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/query-super.html
You can join these arrays of data together by index (element) in the unnest step.
Alternatively can you use json_parse() to create and array of objects and just unnest this.  If you trouble with this please provide a simple test case with expected output and the community can give you a working code sample.
=========================================
Using your data and my best guesses on what you are dealing with here’s what I’ve come up with:
with input as (
    select '["P-01111","P-12224","P-23654"]'::text as id,
        '["1/01/2020","1/02/2022","2/02/2022"]'::text as colo_l2_submitted_telstra_nbn_vha_f__c,
        '["2/01/2023","3/01/2023","4/01/2023"]'::text as colo_l2_submitted_telstra_nbn_vha_a__c
),
sup as (
    select json_parse(id) as id,
        json_parse(colo_l2_submitted_telstra_nbn_vha_f__c) as colo_l2_submitted_telstra_nbn_vha_f__c,
        json_parse(colo_l2_submitted_telstra_nbn_vha_a__c) as colo_l2_submitted_telstra_nbn_vha_a__c
    from input
)
select i as project_id, 
    'colo_l2_submitted_telstra_nbn_vha_f__c' as field_name, s.colo_l2_submitted_telstra_nbn_vha_f__c[index] as field_date
from sup s, s.id i at index
union all 
select i as project_id,
    'colo_l2_submitted_telstra_nbn_vha_a__c' as field_name, s.colo_l2_submitted_telstra_nbn_vha_a__c[index] as field_date
from sup s, s.id i at index;


Hi there, I have done my  best to add sample data, please let me know if this helps as I am still unsure.
